# How to set cygwin sshd language to English?

Tags: cygwin

Why is sshd/cygwin outputting messages in portuguese (yes, I'm in Brazil but even Windows 7 is set to English)? For example:

```
$ net start sshd
O servi▒o solicitado j▒ foi iniciado.

Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 2182.
```

This is really annoying.

I would like to have everything in English.

Already tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/374892/cygwin-bash-g-is-in-japanese-mode-how-to-set-everything-to-english). All LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES, and LANG are set to en_US.UTF-8 but still I get messages in Portuguese.

Comment: It's a bit of a long shot, but what is the output of `type net` from within that same shell?

Comment: `net` is not sshd and not Cygwin... it's a core Windows tool.

Comment: `net` is not sshd and not Cygwin... it's a core Windows tool.